# Can you create an AWS CloudFormation stack on a t2.micro instance?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services

I am trying to do MongoDB on AWS following the [AWS deployment guide](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/mongodb/). It is defaulted to boot up **m5.large** EC2s. However, I am only experimenting so I want to use a free tier EC2. When I add **t2.micro** to the allowed values and set it as default I get an error as pictured below.

[image]

[image]

Is there anyway I can get MongoDB running on AWS with 3 replications using the cloudformation method with free tier **t2.micro** instances.? If not, any better methods?

Comment: Please don't post code and errors are screenshots, but properly formatted code blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MongoDB on AWS - Quick Start](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/mongodb/) has multiple templates that are deployed.

I notice that the `NodeInstanceType` is used and defined in **multiple templates**, presumably with the values passed from the **master** template to the **node** templates. Therefore, your changes will probably need to be made on any template that defines the `NodeInstanceType` parameter. I recommend you check *all* of the templates for such references.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Your totally right! There is a part in the template that creates the replica nodes `"PrimaryReplicaNode0"` and at that point it uses the old templates. I need to replace that with my template somehow because it uses the amazon default `"https://${S3Bucket}.s3.${S3Region}.${AWS::URLSuffix}/${QSS3KeyPrefix}templates/mongodb-node.template",` will look into it, thank you

Comment: I was able to upload my customized template to a S3 bucket and put that in. Worked perfect. Thanks for the tip!